# How to use tlbimp.exe's /keycontainer switch?

Tags: .net, com, interop, tlbimp

Anybody have an example of how to use `tlbimp.exe`'s `/keycontainer` command line switch?

The googles...they don't help.  It's always `/publickey`, or `/keyfile.`  No example of using `/keycontainer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to answer my own question for the sake of anyone else who may find themselves in this situation:

First, you need to put your public/private key into a 'container'. `sn.exe` can do this for you:

```
sn.exe -i MySpecial.pfx MagicContainerName
```

Then you can use `tlbimp.exe` like so:

```
tlbimp.exe MyActiveX.dll /out:MyActiveX.Interop.dll /keycontainer:MagicContainerName
```

Finally, cleanup the container you created:

```
sn.exe -d MagicContainerName
```